# Why doesn't sqldf function see the condition?

Tags: r, date, sqldf

I use sqldf function for data manipuation in R studio. 
And I met a problem that sqldf function doesn't take into account the condition I set up in my query.
For example the code

```
d2 <- sqldf("select a.'n1.0', a.date, a.tot_cap*100/a.'n1.0' as afasf from data a where a.date < '2013-03-01'")
```

gives exact the same result as code

```
d2 <- sqldf("select a.'n1.0', a.date, a.tot_cap*100/a.'n1.0' as afasf from data a").
```

Setting single quotes, double quotes, no quotes at all doesn't help.

Does anybody know what's the problem and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the result of `dput(data2)` command where data2 is the first 40 rows of the initial dataset.

```
structure(list(REGN = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), date = structure(c(14761, 
14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14975, 15006, 15034, 
15065, 15095, 15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 15248, 15279, 15309, 
15706, 15737, 15765, 15796, 15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 
15979, 16010, 16040, 16071, 16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 16222, 
16252, 16283, 16314), class = "Date"), tot_cap = structure(c(3.29680129097603e-316, 
3.27881038454837e-316, 3.31569035934127e-316, 3.42544269478722e-316, 
3.46449744773999e-316, 3.76857311386686e-316, 3.83375272419446e-316, 
3.89781752479879e-316, 3.88106524094525e-316, 3.91119504385185e-316, 
3.54278081534629e-316, 3.66904833254234e-316, 3.84160896084211e-316, 
3.83063042693901e-316, 3.87586035817945e-316, 3.98758302742101e-316, 
4.04557250040469e-316, 4.19023427922167e-316, 4.27870651560933e-316, 
5.55371435659506e-316, 5.45611929687006e-316, 5.73639651252866e-316, 
5.74625569130456e-316, 5.74576631928235e-316, 5.79667637503333e-316, 
5.86047635645149e-316, 5.66957630781748e-316, 6.16857297583704e-316, 
6.25638237375425e-316, 6.32633446059442e-316, 6.54992194176386e-316, 
6.44650520772079e-316, 6.41496840466797e-316, 6.51734725500882e-316, 
6.52890122716964e-316, 6.49014508749322e-316, 6.47399926921995e-316, 
6.49043322657787e-316, 6.47938176858544e-316, 6.65456810876004e-316
), class = "integer64"), bas_cap = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.24913731265079e-316, 5.71723269425777e-316, 
5.71723269425777e-316, 5.72079658738749e-316, 5.71723269425777e-316, 
5.71723269425777e-316, 5.71723269425777e-316, 5.84030513832873e-316
), class = "integer64"), osn_cap = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.24913731265079e-316, 5.71723269425777e-316, 
5.71723269425777e-316, 5.72079658738749e-316, 5.71723269425777e-316, 
5.71723269425777e-316, 5.71723269425777e-316, 5.84030513832873e-316
), class = "integer64"), n1.0 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14.13, 13.91, 13.74, 13.25, 
13.11, 13.59, 13.07, 13.06), n1.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.65, 12.3, 12.11, 11.75, 
11.65, 12.04, 11.61, 11.53), n1.2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.65, 12.3, 12.12, 11.77, 
11.66, 12.06, 11.62, 11.54), n1 = c(13.96, 13.66, 15.07, 15.75, 
15.49, 15.87, 15.7, 16.32, 16.17, 16.67, 14.97, 15.06, 15.22, 
15.02, 14.68, 14.42, 13.5, 13.29, 13.1, 13.25, 12.53, 13.28, 
13.35, 13.42, 13.67, 14.14, 13.1, 14.13, 14.13, 14.55, 14.53, 
14.51, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 40L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please share your input data, or a representative example, by adding the output of `dput(example_df)` to the question. Otherwise this issue you're asking about is not reproducible

Comment: I would be very thanful to you if you help me to load data to the site.

Comment: You can do so by running `dput(example_df)` and copying the ouput, then editing this question to paste the output at the bottom. It is possible this will be too large if you have a big table. In that case you would need to create an example data frame that has the same issue, possibly by subsetting your original data frame.

Comment: May be you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665367/r-sqldf-not-being-selective-in-date-range-criteria) Possible duplicate

Comment: Based on G. Grothendieck's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933142/filter-by-date-range-in-sqldf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996390/sqldf-how-to-query-based-on-a-date-condition), the default DB engine for sqldf only sees dates as their numeric representation. So it seems you need to do `a.date < 15765` to get the filter to work. (15765 is `as.numeric(as.Date('2013-03-01'))`)

Comment: The comments you've mentioned helped me to overcome my issues. Thanks at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here:

- single quotes are used for quoting constants.  Use double quotes to quote variable names.
- SQLite does not support a Date type so the dates are read in as numbers (number of days since the UNIX Epoch) and then the statement is attempting to compare that number to a character string.
- although not wrong you don't really need the alias `a` since there is only one data frame so there cannot be any confusion as to what is being referenced.
- the question refers to `data2` but `data` is used in the R code.  We have changed the R code to use `data2`.

See the links given in the comments under the question for more information.

### SQLite

Using the default SQLite backend, we preface `sqldf` with `fn$` to cause it to run anything between backticks in R and replace that expression with the result of that run.

```
d2 <- fn$sqldf("select \"n1.0\", date, tot_cap * 100/ \"n1.0\" as afasf 
  from data2 
  where date < `as.Date('2013-03-01')`")
```

### H2

Alternately, use the H2 backend.  (As with SQLite, the H2 database is included in the R driver so you don't have to install it separately but you do need to ensure that you have Java installed -- fortunately that is extremely simple as it has an automated installation procedure.) That database does have a Date type and is able to compare such dates with correclty formatted character strings representing dates.

```
library(RH2)  # <----------note

d3 <- fn$sqldf("select \"n1.0\", date, tot_cap * 100 / \"n1.0\" as afasf 
  from data2
  where date < '2013-03-01'")
```

Be sure to detach RH2 from the search path if you want to resume using SQLite.